# How do I find the smallest difference between a given number and every element in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, subtraction

Say I have:

`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

and the integer

`6`

I want to compare `6` with every element in the list and return the element with the smallest absolute value difference which in this case is `4`. Is there an efficient `Numpy` way to do it?

Comment: FWIW, in plain Python, you could do `min(lst, key=lambda u:abs(u-6))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `argmin` on the absolute difference to extract the index, which can then be used to extract the element:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

a[np.abs(a - 6).argmin()]
# 4
```

Comment: How do I get the index of that 4?

Comment: `np.abs(a - 6).argmin()` should give the index of the minimum difference.